# Stored procedure through Data Service

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, wcf-data-services

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_NEXT_ID(NEXTID OUT INTEGER)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT SQC_RS_PEDIDO.NEXTVAL INTO NEXTID FROM DUAL;
END GET_NEXT_ID;
```

To get the next ID. Then I added this stored procedure on a data service and imported function.

The automatic code that is created on my data service is:

```
public ObjectResult<Nullable<global::System.Decimal>> GET_NEXT_ID(ObjectParameter nEXTID)
{
    return base.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<global::System.Decimal>>("GET_NEXT_ID", nEXTID);
}
```

Then to expose this on my data service I used:

```
[WebGet]
public ObjectResult<decimal?> GET_NEXT_ID()
{
    return this.CurrentDataSource.GET_NEXT_ID(new ObjectParameter("NEXTID", typeof(Decimal)));
}
```

But I'm getting an exception:

> The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring a function in the database rather than a procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NEXT_ID RETURN INTEGER IS

NEXTID INTEGER;

BEGIN

   SELECT SQC_RS_PEDIDO.NEXTVAL INTO NEXTID FROM DUAL;

   RETURN NEXTID;

END GET_NEXT_ID;
```

Comment: When I run that I get the error:

Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Also:

[Error] Syntax check (1: 40): Found:  'IS' Expecting: RETURN   -or-   (   -or-   WRAPPED   -or-   TIMESTAMP

Comment: I presume this is Oracle. Can you post the error message?

Comment: Yes is Oracle. When I test the code gives me:

[Error] Syntax check (1: 40): Found:  'IS' Expecting: RETURN   -or-   (   -or-   WRAPPED   -or-   TIMESTAMP

Comment: Now I added the function through data model, but how should I use the function? I can't use "Function Import" now

Comment: This could be due to a missing privilege if you are connecting via a schema other than the one in which the database object is created.

Comment: I added the Function to my EF model and when I run:
return this.CurrentDataSource.ExecuteFunction("Entities.GET_NEXT_ID");

I get the exception
The FunctionImport 'GET_NEXT_ID' could not be found in the container

Answer (score 0):

Your query expects the reader to return the ID as a select, but your stored procedure is setup to pass the parameter back through an output variable.  The simple fix would be just return the value from the select statement and not insert it into the output variable.

Comment: Could you put an example?

Comment: I don't understand the database syntax (Oracle?) but basically in standard SQL I would do: select NEXTVAL.  You have to select the ID from the DB, not return it as an output variable, and not return it using the RETURN statement, to get your WCF code to work.  Or change the WCF code but I don't know exactly the syntax for ExecuteFunction to change that too.